# JS menu issue with preventDefault who close my menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, frontend, wordpress-theming, preventdefault

it is my first question on Stackoverflow after many years of reading answers here. Sorry for my english, it is not my nativelanguage.

I develop on wordpress a system to open and close the menu and open the submenu.

When I open the submenu my menu closes despite I prevent the click on a tag

```
let openMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a');
let arrayLinkMenu = Array.from(openMenu);
for(let i = 0; i < arrayLinkMenu.length; i++){
    arrayLinkMenu[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      arrayLinkMenu[i].nextElementSibling.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    })
}
```

I tried with `return false` but I get the same issue.

When I click, it creates an `a` tag with `#` as URL. It's like this my page refresh but not... I never see my web browser refresh really my page.

I put the code who open and close the menu, we never know

```
    /**If menu is open create div with button close menu and add interation to submenu*/
    //Verify the click on the button
    let buttonMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('mobile_nav');
    buttonMenu[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let menuClosed = document.getElementsByClassName('closed-menu');
        if (menuClosed.length > 0){
            menuClosed[0].remove();
        }
        //if it' open create div or a tag
        if(!buttonMenu[0].classList.contains('opened')){
            let aTag = document.createElement('a');
            aTag.href = '#';
            aTag.innerHTML = '<img src="url_image" />';
            aTag.classList.add('closed-menu')
            let mobileMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('et_mobile_menu');
            mobileMenu[0].appendChild(aTag);
            
            //create action to close menu
            let menuClosed = document.getElementsByClassName('closed-menu');
            if(menuClosed.length > 0){
                let mobileNav = document.getElementsByClassName('mobile_nav')
                menuClosed[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    mobileNav[0].classList.remove('opened');
                    mobileNav[0].classList.add('closed');
                    event.preventDefault();
                })
            }
            
            
            //click on menu with subMenu
            let openMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a');
            let arrayLinkMenu = Array.from(openMenu);
            for(let i = 0; i < arrayLinkMenu.length; i++){
                arrayLinkMenu[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                    arrayLinkMenu[i].nextElementSibling.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                })
            }
            
        }else{
            // take an ellement and remove it to not have many ellements on same menu
            let menuClosed = document.getElementsByClassName('closed-menu');
            if (menuClosed.length > 0){
                menuClosed[0].remove();
            }
        }
        
    })
```

Thanks per advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `stopImmediatePropagation()` so you are sure that not even other event listeners registered on the element itself are executed.

Comment: I try with stopImmediatePropagation() but I have the same result.
The menu closed when I clicked on link